# Linux or window is the same :p -> HttpException('Invalid HTTP request form (expected: authority or absolute, got: relative)')

Tags: python, pip, reverse-proxy, mitmproxy

I am new to mitmproxy.org library. On doc what i have seen this library has some features that im really interested to use.
I have some couple of question about this package i have tried in both Windows 10, and ubuntu 18.04 but same result in both.
Support should be on installation setup.
I have found this library since 2 or 3 days, the most important part is that i cannot make it run.

ON WINDOW 10:
I have installed:
mitmproxy throw pip with command `'pip install mitmproxy'`
and throw windows installer throw 'https://snapshots.mitmproxy.org/6.0.2/mitmproxy-6.0.2-windows-installer.exe'

When i use this line of code

```
mitmdump -p 443 --mode reverse:http://example.com # it works just fine as it needs to in local ip http://localhost:443
```

When i use this line of code

```
mitmproxy -s anatomy.py # fails to run on local ip http://localhost:8080 with error message 'Error: mitmproxy's console interface is not supported on Windows. You can run mitmdump or mitmweb instead.'

mitmdump -s anatomy.py # fails to run on local ip http://localhost:8080 with error message 'HTTP protocol error in client request: Invalid HTTP request form (expected: authority or absolute, got: relative)'
```

ON UBUNTU 18.04:
I have installed:
mitmproxy throw pip with command `'pip install mitmproxy'`
When i use this line of code

```
mitmdump -p 443 --mode reverse:http://example.com # fails to run on local ip http://localhost:8080 with error message 'HTTP protocol error in client request: Invalid HTTP request form (expected: authority or absolute, got: relative)'
```

When i use this line of code

```
mitmproxy -s anatomy.py | mitmdump -s anatomy.py #fails to run on local ip http://localhost:8080 with error message 'HTTP protocol error in client request: Invalid HTTP request form (expected: authority or absolute, got: relative)'
```

All, the best

Comment: Why do you start mitmproxy in reverse mode? Setting up revers mode is way more complicated as it works only on Linux and requires to reroute IP traffic using iptables.

Comment: hi, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150978/robert , bcs reverse mode first it was just for testing purpose, and second it was the only way i could make it run in my windows machine meantime on linux as you can see from my output nothing worked for me to make it run on local server no clue what am i doing wrong